# event.preventDefault() behaving differently in iOS 14 and above

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview, ios14

I am using Javascript to perform actions in WKWebView in an iPad application which loads some locally generated HTMLString(Say a page in a book as text). User interactions like selecting a word is dealt using javascript as below function.

Also a pan gesture is added to WKWebView to perform actions when user pans on each word in different directions(different actions for different angles).

The below code is working perfectly for versions **below** iOS 14. But above that the pan gesture is not correctly invoked in versions above iOS 14(Not registering minimum points needed for calculating angle to perform action).

```
function highlightSelectedStart(event)  { //ontouchstart 
    
    var clickedObject=elementFromDocumentPoint(event.touches[0].screenX, event.touches[0].screenY);
    var TagID = clickedObject.id;
    firstNode = clickedObject;
    selectClass.className = 'noSelect';
    previousTagID  = TagID;
    deselectAllHighlightedElement();
    if (window.getSelection)
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection)
        document.selection.empty();
    window.location = "didwordselected:"+TagID;
    event.preventDefault();   //<== *This here behaves differently in iOS 14*
}

function highlightSelectedMove (event) { //ontouchmove
    
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedObject=elementFromDocumentPoint(event.changedTouches[0].screenX, event.changedTouches[0].screenY);
    
    if  (findPosY(firstNode) == findPosY(clickedObject)) {
        clickedObject = clickedObject.childNodes[0];
        var TagID = clickedObject.parentNode.id;
        lastNode = clickedObject.parentNode;
        selectAndHighlightElement(TagID);
        window.location = "didwordselected:"+TagID;
    } 
}
```

If **event.preventDefault()** is removed from touchstart function, pan actions will work well in all iOS versions, but the touchStart function execution is delayed(I suppose it is waiting for double-click).

I would greatly appreciate if someone can tell me why behaviour is different in iOS 14 or above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who stumbles up on the same issue.

All issues was because of the click delay for double tap zoom which is said to be get disabled along with click delay when viewport is changed to the snippet below.

No matter what I do the WKWebView displaying its content outside the frame with scroll is not respecting the viewport given like below

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'>
```

This disables the double tap zoom, but click delay is still present while user taps on the word.

Thanks to this [script](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) from ftlabs which eliminated the click delay which in turn rescued me from using event.preventDefault()